# Angular ui-router debugging

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, partial-views

I have the following arrangement:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: ''
    })

    .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile/view',
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/profile.tpl.html'
    })

    .state('profile.view', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/profile-view.tpl.html',
        controller: 'profileController',
        controllerAs: 'pc'
    })

    .state('profile.edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        templateUrl: 'static/templates/profile-edit.tpl.html',
        controller: 'editProfileController',
        controllerAs: 'editCtrl'
    })
    ;
```

What I intend to do is - I have *some common partial content* between the `profile.view` and the `profile.edit` states.

The common part is supposed inside the `profile` state. But the current arrangement is failing and `/profile/view` **DOES NOT** render any of the partials.

> No errors reported to console.

Edit:
Here is `profile.tpl.html`

```
<div flex flex-gt-sm="50" flex-offset-gt-sm="25" layout="row" layout-align="center">
    <div ui-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit 2:

After adding `abstract: true` the `profile.view` state started working fine. But `profile.edit` state keeps redirecting to `/`. Sort of **following the `.otherwise('/')`** rule

Comment: are you trying to load **view** and **edit** inside another **ui-view** which is in **profile.tpl.html**?

Comment: Or asked more directly, does your template for the "profile" state include a `ui-view` directive? It's required b/c the "view" and "edit" states are child states of "profile".

Comment: yes it does have a `ui-view`, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question:

All I was missing was `abstract: true` in the `profile` state

Edit:

following things completely solved it for me:

1. `abstract: true` in `profile` state
2. `url: '/profile'` in `profile` state
3. `url: '/view'` in `profile.view` state
4. `url: '/edit'` in `profile.edit` state